# Should Mixed effects models with repeated cases have the same results as Weighted Mixed effects model?

Tags: mixed-model, stata, survey-weights

I have a conceptual question that might also be a question about STATA and GLLAMM.

**Conceptually:** Should duplicating some groups in a mixed effects model have the same effect as giving those groups a sample weight of two? I think it should but STATA's GLLAMM doesnt' agree.

To explain further: 
I have a data set with 18 groups and 10 observations in each group. I take the first 3 groups and duplicate them (ie change the group number but keep the exact same variables/outcomes) I then run a mixed effects model with the sample weights of all level 1 observations in the data set fixed to be 1.

To compare I then take the original data and change the sample weights for the level one observations for the first three groups to 2. The result is not the same. The estimated parameters are similar but not the same and the likelihood is not the same.

Does anyone know why this would be?

**Code to reproduce:** 
get data from https://github.com/Claire-Kelley/sleepstudy (based on the sleep study data from the lme4 package in R)

```
import delimited ss_doubled.csv
generate int intercept = 1
eq sub_eq: subject
eq  intercept: intercept 
gllamm reaction days, i(subject) family(gau) link(id) pweight(w) nip(29) nrf(1) eqs(intercept) adapt
```

And then the weighted version

```
import delimited ss_weighted.csv
generate int intercept = 1
eq sub_eq: subject
eq  intercept: intercept 
gllamm reaction days, i(subject) family(gau) link(id) pweight(w) nip(29) nrf(1) eqs(intercept) adapt
```

Comment: Move the doubled weights from w1 to w2 and it works for me!